# Highcharts 3 like menu button won't display

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, highcharts

So I am trying to add a highcharts chart with an export button.

I have reference to the two needed scripts: exporting.js and highcharts.js

How it should look like

[image]

How it looks now

[image]

How can I make it display properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using CSS styled version of exporting.js, styled version is located under js foler:

`https://code.highcharts.com/js/modules/exporting.js`

File for non CSS styled version:

`https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js`

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/w6tdcLyu/

Comment: you are right, I didn't notice there are 2 different versions, thank you!!